# ETL Data from Amazon DMS to S3 to Redshift

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, etl

I am currently building a data lake within S3 and have successfully moved data from a mysql DB to S3 using DMS.  Within DMS I chose the option 'Migrate existing data and replicate ongoing changes'.  I transformed the data to csv, but in the future will probably choose parquet.  This method creates an initial csv file that has all the raw data from the database tables.  It then creates subsequent csv files with inserts, deletes, updates.

Now I am looking for a strategy to copy the data from S3 into Redshift.  I am looking for a strategy to copy the bulk data and copy the continual changes from S3 into Redshift.  I will likely need to aggregate and summarize much of this data.  Preferably I'll use AWS Glue, which uses Python.  This ETL process will have to read from csv files in S3 and know to ignore files that have already been processed.

How can I facilitate this? Any ideas are welcome.  Ideally I'm hoping for some Python (or Java) scripts that precisely do the process as described.

Thanks.

Comment: why did you set up DMS to go from mysql->S3? rather than mysql->redshift? i.e. load all data to redshift "staging" area then run your data transformations directly on redshift?

Comment: As I mentioned I am building a data lake.   The raw data needs to stay in S3  which is the dedicated lake.

Comment: How did you handle the updates coming from mysql to S3 ? Are you merging it someway or what

Answer (score 1):

Recommend setting up AWS Glue to automatically watch the S3 destination and  convert the CSV into Parquet. 
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/what-is-glue.html
- https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-samples

Then use Amazon Redshift Spectrum to selectively load and/or query the data directly from the data lake.
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-getting-started-using-spectrum.html

Comment: This is a good answer, just make sure that you really need a data lake, as you will be adding significant complication and expense over a redshift centric solution

Answer (score 0):

Using **Lambda** functions and triggers, you can setup in such a way that **Redshift** **cluster** is automatically loaded when a file is uploaded to **S3**.

Refer to below link

[A Zero-Administration Amazon Redshift Database Loader](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/a-zero-administration-amazon-redshift-database-loader/)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to solving this problem would be to use Redshift as a target directly since

> During a database migration to Amazon Redshift, AWS DMS first moves data to an Amazon S3 bucket. When the files reside in an Amazon S3 bucket, AWS DMS then transfers them to the proper tables in the Amazon Redshift data warehouse.

This last step happens via the COPY command and uses intermediate CSV files that are written to S3. If you don't want Redshift to create a new bucket you can also add

> A custom S3 bucket as intermediate storage for data migrated to Amazon Redshift.

This intermediate target could be whatever path you have defined for your data lake. Moreover, you can create Glue jobs that convert your data to Parquet or any other format inside your data lake.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dms-redshift-target-endpoint/